# Optimizing weights in keras based on value got through model.predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, keras

I am using an rnn in Keras to predict electricity demand, to create a probabilistic forecast. I first train the model using a multiple quantile regression approach i.e., produce 99 outputs and then score the predictions of the model using a separate metric. This metric is more of a counts value (expected value-observed/ expected value) and I cannot initially train my model on it. I want to optimize my weights on the second metric.

```
def qcs(expected, observed):
    return ((observed-expected)**2/expected/len(expected)).sum(0)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you initially train your model on it?

Comment: Can you explain what the network is predicting and how the counting for the metric is done?

Comment: As long as your second metric is differentiable,  you can definitely do it. Otherwise, you have to find some approximate/soft-version of the interested metric.

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos I can't initially train the model on it as I need to use multiple regression techniques as I am generating probabilistic forecasts. And the metric I am using basically subtracts the expected value from the observed value and divides it by the expected value. To calculate this particular value we need multiple predictions. Almost a year's worth of predictions.

Comment: @Chinni The network is predicting what the electricity demand will be for 9 am, for a whole year. I first train the model on the pinball loss [link] (https://www.lokad.com/pinball-loss-function-definition)and then the metric I am using basically subtracts the expected value from the observed value and divides it by the expected value.

Comment: @user36624 my second loss function is not differentiable.

Comment: Your loss seems perfectly ok to be used normally in the model.

Comment: @DanielMöller I can't train my model on the second loss function as I need to create a multiple quantile regression which is not possible with it.

Comment: Can you please explain? I can't see the problem.

Comment: @DanielMöller so, to create multiple quantiles, i.e., 99 predictions for each timestep I use the Pinball Loss function. The second loss function actually requires me to have existing multiple predictions to calculate the loss. Also, I defined my second metric. In the question. Have a look

Comment: @DanielMöller also, I get my loss as Nans